# Loop and variable php

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I never use php and I have to do a simple things; I have to take a string, substring it, explode it and then explode the string of the array I found after the first explode. Finally i have to save the string in the db. This is the code;

```
mysql_connect("xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx","xxxx","xxxxxx");

mysql_select_db("app");

$stringa = substr($rawData, 12, -1);    //works
$prima_sep = explode("%%", $stringa);   //works

$i = 0;
while ($i < count($prima_sep)) {
    $a = 0;
    $b = 1;

    $seconda_sep = explode("&&", $prima_sep[$i]);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (DATA, STRING) VALUES ('".$seconda_sep[$a]."', '".$seconda_sep[$b]."')");

    $i++;
}
```

$rawDate looks like this

```
"stringa":"22/5/2014&&blablabla%%23/5/2014&&bla1bla1bla1"
```

I dont understand why if I use this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (DATA, STRING) VALUES ('ok', '".count($seconda_sep)."')");
```

and count($prima_sep) is = 2 I found correctly 2 row in the db but if i use

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (DATA, STRING) VALUES ('".$seconda_sep[$a]."', '".$seconda_sep[$b]."')");
```

and count($prima_sep) is = 2 I found just 1 row in the db.

What I have to do for insert the right number of row??

Thanks

Comment: first of all I would suggest change mysql_ functions to mysqli_ or PDO since mysql_ functions are deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP http://www.php.net//manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: Add `$rawData` value and DB model to your answer to clarify

Comment: We need your db structure for that!

Comment: @Sal00m the rawData has variable lenght but is like this: 22/5/2014&&blablabla%%23/5/2014&&bla1bla1bla1.....and I have to put the date in DATE of the db and the second string in STRING of the db, nothing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this, I am not sure why you discard the first 12 characters but processing that rawData can be done quite simply like this.

```
$rawData = '22/5/2014&&blablabla%%23/5/2014&&bla1bla1bla1%%24/5/2014&&bla1bla1bla2';

$rows = explode("%%", $rawData); 

foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
   $fields = explode('&&',$row);

   $sql = "INSERT INTO test (DATA, STRING) VALUES ('{$fields[0]}', '{$fields[1]}')";
   mysql_query($sql);
}
```

This would generate:

```
INSERT INTO test (DATA, STRING) VALUES ('22/5/2014', 'blablabla')
INSERT INTO test (DATA, STRING) VALUES ('23/5/2014', 'bla1bla1bla1')
INSERT INTO test (DATA, STRING) VALUES ('24/5/2014', 'bla1bla1bla2')
```

Comment: I dont understand what was wrong before (I come from java and objective c and I thought was right) but now work!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You should simple have:

```
$stringa = $rawData;
```

and not

```
$stringa = substr($rawData, 12, -1);
```

Otherwise you create 2 element array with following data :

```
  0 => string 'lablabla' 
  1 => string '23/5/2014&&bla1bla1bla'
```

As you see for first element when you explode it using `&&` delimiter you won't have 2 elements and that's why data for first element is not inserted into database.

Comment: I correct the rawData, i need substring for delete some extra character. Then I have this:
22/5/2014&&blablabla%%23/5/2014&&bla1bla1bla1.....
and I have to separate this string